# Error envio de mail en Laravel Cpanel

Tags: php, laravel, phpmailer

Tengo esta ruta que envia un mail

```
Route::get("send/email", "ReportesController@mail");
```

Este es mi funcion de enviar mail en mi Reportes Controller

```
   public function mail(){
        Mail::to('correo@corre.com')->send(new SendEmail());
        return "Email enviado";
    }
```

Y mi sendEmail

```
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class SendEmail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject('Reporte')->view('email');
    }
}
```

Y mi vista email.blade.php solo es un h1 de Prueba que dice **Hola Mundo**

Tengo esta configuracion en mi .env

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.dominio.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxx@dominio.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=xxx@dominio.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

En mi **localhost:8000/send/mail** si me funciona y envia el email pero en mi **dominio.com/send/email** me aparece la pantalla de 500 y en la respuesta solo me muestra Server Error sin ningun tipo de error, no se a que se deba

Comment: Revisa el log de errores en el servidor, ahí vas a tener el detalle completo.

Comment: Es posible que su proveedor no admita el envío a través de TLS o que necesite instalar el certificado. ¿Has intentado usar otro servidor de correo?, Puedes hacer la prueba con mailtrap para ver si es un problema con su proveedor de correos.

Answer (score 0):

Yo puse la configuración así y me funcionó

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=midominio.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=xxx@midominio.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=xxx@midominio.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).